# [<TestingAPI.Album 0x6100000ff300> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key albumId

Tags: ios, iphone

I am new to iOS development and been trying to jump into swift straight away. I am trying to work with APIs and trying to learn myself. I've build this test Collection view along with the model to get the data however when I run the app I get a crash. Been trying to find a solution with no luck.

I've seen few that have the same crash however mostly due to a xib file which I am not using. I am building the app solely in code.

#### AlbumId

```
import UIKit

class AlbumId: NSObject {

    var albumId: NSNumber?

    static func fetchAlbums() {

        let urlString = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error ?? "")
                return
            }

            do {

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)

                var albums = [Album]()

                for dict in json as! [Any] {
                    let album = Album(dictionary: dict as! [String: Any])
                    album.setValuesForKeys(dict as! [String : Any])
                    albums.append(album)
                }

            } catch let err {
                print(err)
            }

            }.resume()

    }
}
```

#### Album

```
class Album: NSObject {
    var id: NSNumber?
    var title: String?
    var url: String?
    var thumbnailUrl: String?

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        super.init()

        id = dictionary["id"] as? NSNumber
        title = dictionary["title"] as? String
        url = dictionary["url"] as? String
        thumbnailUrl = dictionary["thumbnailUrl"] as? String
    }
}
```

Comment: Please attach the class from where you are initialising AlbumId class

Comment: Why you defined var albumId: NSNumber? at the top. You should post all code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `Album` does not have a property called `albumId` which means that it is not [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/) compliant for that key.

It seems your JSON response has a key "albumId", but since your class is not KVC-compliant (it doesn't have an "albumId" property) using `setValuesForKeys` fails because `setValuesForKeys` requires that the instance must be KVC compliant for all of the keys in the dictionary.

Without a little knowledge regarding the JSON response, we can only make recommendations based on assumptions.

Your options are:

1. Change the property "id" to "albumId" on class `Album`
2. Change your API so the JSON key is simply "id"
3. Override `setValueForKey` and redirect "albumId" to your "id" property.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the model does not contain the property `albumId`.

Calling the KVC method `setValuesForKeys` is redundant anyway since you are initializing the object from the dictionary. There are only a few rare cases in Swift where KVC is useful. This is none of them. And inheritance from `NSObject` is actually not needed either.

The received JSON has `id` **and** `albumId` keys, so add the latter to the model and use `Int` rather than `NSNumber`. This code uses non-optional constants (`let`) with default values empty string / 0

```
class Album {
    let albumId : Int
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let url: String
    let thumbnailUrl: String

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {

        albumId = dictionary["albumId"] as? Int ?? 0
        id = dictionary["id"] as? Int ?? 0
        title = dictionary["title"] as? String ?? ""
        url = dictionary["url"] as? String ?? ""
        thumbnailUrl = dictionary["thumbnailUrl"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

Now populate the `albums` array, as always `.mutableContainers` is completely meaningless in Swift

```
   if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String: Any]] else { return }

   var albums = [Album]()

   for dict in json {
       let album = Album(dictionary: dict)
       albums.append(album)
   }
```

or in a *swiftier* way

```
  var albums = json.map { Album(dictionary: $0)  }
```